# How to lock indexed db

Tags: indexeddb

I am developing a chrome app and i am using indexedDB as a database. I would like to know how to lock the database so that unauthorized user will not be able to see the database data but when the user enter userId and password for the database it should allow user to access it.

Comment: What does authorized user vs an unauthorized mean in your context? Who are you worried about? Where does the user enter their userId and password?

Answer (score 1):

IndexedDB respects [single origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) and other web site / app will not access your site data.

For your concern, confidential data must NOT available until user login for the first time. After that, it is OK to keep confidential data in the web app. You may also want to encrypt using [client side encryption](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/doc/example/encryption.html) for some data.